# How do I use a Freemarker template to display a JavaScript array in html?

Tags: javascript, html, freemarker

If I generate an array in JavaScript, is it possible to configure a Freemarker template in the JavaScript code, in order to generate html which dynamically displays the array's elements?

Answer (score 1):

If we are talking about JavaScript running in the browser, then no, because FreeMarker runs on the server side before the page is sent to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

freemarker can display javascript.

```js
function doSomeThing(){
<#if !user??>
 location.href="www.xxx.com/login.htm"
</#if>

 other js
}
```

if you want to create dynamically js depend by the some arg
you can use macro to define yourself function. to show some different js code snippet by the input arg.